# Does APN device token depend on push notification permission

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

If user says no to push notification permission in the initial launch of application, will the APN device token be received by the application ?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** This answer is incorrect. Please look at the answer below. I cannot delete that as it is an accepted answer.

User must give permission for you to get the device token.

If user gives permission, `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` method is executed in `AppDelegate` and you'll get the device token.

If user refuses to give permission, `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error` method is executed and you'll only get corresponding `NSError` object.

Comment: This is not accurate. You can still get a token for a silent push. Look at **talshahar**'s answer below.

Answer (score 23):

There is a very important exception you should be aware of. If you enable the Background Mode "Remote Notifications", you will get a token from iOS regardless of the user's response to the permission question. You will be able to send silent push notifications to your app using this token (a push with the content-available key set to 1 in the 'aps' section of the json 
silent notification means if your app is in the foreground you will get a hit in didReceiveRemoteNotification and if your app is in the background it will also get a call (in the background) to the same delegate function. 
BUT - this will not be visible to the user. so it still gives you a way to communicate with your app, albeit a limited one.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I've verified it experimentally, and am using this approach in my own app. The subscription event is now invoked with the device token regardless of whether the user accepts or rejects -- but it does still _wait_ to invoke until the user makes their selection.

Comment: this answer is correct. i'm deleting my answer to avoid misguidence, sorry about that

Answer (score -1):

No, you need to have the user permission to get the token